# How do I work out the probability of failure in the described situation?

Tags: statistics, probability

I'm looking for some help finding a formula to work out the following:

If I have a probability of an event occurring, p, and a maximum number of times that event can occur, x, before "failure", I need to know how to work out what the max population supported would be to ensure x is never reached (or has a y% chance of reaching, e.g. say y = 5%).

Hypothetical example:
Say I'm running an online betting game that has a "bank" of $100 which is replenished every hour. The game a user can play has a probability of winning (p) for a user in a given hour of 0.2, max one play per hour per user. If a user wins then it costs the bank $10. So max wins allowable (x) for any hour before the "bank" is empty is 10. The question is how many players can I support so that the likelihood of the bank hitting empty is < 5% (y)? And what is the formula for this so I can try different p, x and y to get different results?

Any insight / help much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out that I need to use a Binomial Distribution with an area calculation (if that's not right or I've missed something, please let me know!):
[image: Binomial Disribution]